# How do I ignore all svn, bin, and obj folders when creating a git repository?

Tags: git, svn, unix

I'm totally new to git and want to create a repository in a directory that has existing *.svn* folders and compiled folders *bin* and *obj*.  After running init on a directory, what is the command to ignore these folders? I'm using GitBash on Windows.

Comment: Use [.gitignore](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) and search a little bit by yourself before asking…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simplest and shareable way is to create a file called [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) in the project's root directory with this content:

```
.svn
bin
obj
```

You can do that quickly from the command line with:

```
echo .svn >> .gitignore
echo bin >> .gitignore
echo obj >> .gitignore
```

Commit your .gitignore file to the repo, and everyone can benefit from it. Alternately, add .gitignore to the .gitignore file, and it will be ignored as well. Note that if this is a clone of an SVN repo, you can also use `git svn create-ignore` or `git svn show-ignore`. The former will reads the svn:ignore property and creates matching .gitignore files in all the appropriate directories. I prefer the latter, which lists out all the "ignore patterns" in a format that can be appended to a root .gitignore file.

Comment: Thank you...unfortunately it's been a while (since college) since I've been in a linux or unix style prompt....What's the easiest way to create this file with those values in it?

Comment: @Dan: Updated my answer with commands. Also, any text editor will work fine. (Don't consider Notepad a text editor!)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!  Some of the commands in the examples on the next were not working.

Comment: I know this is over a year old, but if someone stumbles across this post like I did, I thought I'd share.  Github offers a range of common ignore patterns here: https://github.com/github/gitignore You can `cat` multiple documents into a single **.gitignore** e.g. `cat CSharp.gitignore >> .gitignore`.

Comment: This wont work if the .svn is nested inside another folder